# How to change the text size in a matplotlib Button?

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-widget

I have a button in matplotlib, i.e.

```
myButton = Button(axpos, 'This is a button')
```

How do I make the text inside the button smaller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change the font size of a matplotlib text, use `text.set_fontsize(12)`. 
To get the text of the button, use `myButton.label`.

Combine the two:

```
myButton.label.set_fontsize(12)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this: `myButton.label.set_fontsize('smaller')` OR you can put in the particular size you want: `myButton.label.set_fontsize(10)`